# Oracle database Date to Timezone format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX

Tags: sql, select, timezone, sql-date-functions

I'm trying to retrieve a timestamp date field from database using a `Select` query such that the timestamp date should be returned as `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSXXX` format. I'm able to process it using SimpleDateFormat class in Java, but when I am trying to run it as a simple select query in SQL Developer and couldn't find sources.

Field value in the database: `09-MAR-16 08.30.37.640392000 AM`

Expecting to return:  `2016-03-09T08:30:37.640-07:00`